# Could not find store using redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Console is throwing the following error:

> Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Form(Form))". Either wrap the root component in a < Provider >, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Form(Form))".

Done everything as said in redux-form tutorial, previously store was working with a mock reducer.

The line in which the error appears is where render() is executed -take a look at index.js file-.

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { devToolsEnhancer } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';


export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, devToolsEnhancer());

  return { store };
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Root from './Root';
import './index.css';
import App from './whitesheet-components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const { store } = configureStore();
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('root');

render(
  <App>
    <Root store={store} />
  </App>,
  MOUNT_NODE,
);


registerServiceWorker();
```

**Root.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store} />
);

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default Root;
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
// use combineReducers when they are more than one
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form';
import mockReducer from './mockReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  mockReducer,
  form,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import titleField from './titleField';

const Form = (props) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit, submitting,
  } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field component={titleField} />
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
            Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={submitting} onClick={() => console.log('boton para agregar input')}>
            +
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

Form.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  submitting: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};


// validate: nombreFuncion, // <--- validation function given to redux-form
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'exerciseCreatorForm', // a unique identifier for this form
})(Form);
```

**ExerciseCreator.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form';


import './styles.css';

const ExerciseCreator = () => (
  <div className="component-exercise-creator">
    <Form />
  </div>
);

export default ExerciseCreator;
```

Comment: Where do you put your `Form` component?

Comment: Post the component which renders `<Form>`

Comment: added that file at last @Tr1et

Comment: Is your `ExerciseCreator` lying somewhere in the `App` component?

Comment: yes, **ExerciseCreator** is inside **Home** and **Home** is inside **App**

`const App = () => (
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Router>
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the provider wraps the your `App` component, not the other way around. Like this:

```
// Root.js
// ...other codes...
const Root = ({ store, children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
);
// ...other codes...

// index.js
// ...other codes...
render(
  <Root store={store}>
    <App />
  </Root>,
  MOUNT_NODE,
);
// ...other codes...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! can you explain me why it was working the other way before redux-form?

Comment: `Redux` use React's `Context` API to store the state, and the `Context` can only be accessible by its child components. The `Provider` is the component to init the `Context`. Use may view the `Context` API [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).